# Logical proof using equivalencies

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, recreational-mathematics

I am trying to do a question which goes like this:

> Show that  (P ∨((P∧( P ∨~Q)) ∧~Q)) ∧(Q →(Q∧~P)) ≡ (P ∧~Q), using the logical equivalence.

So this is how i went about doing it:

(Q →(Q∧~P)) = (~Q ∨ (Q ^ ~P)) using implication equivalence

(P∧( P ∨~Q) ∧~Q) = (P^P) ∨ (P^~Q) ^ ~Q using distributive law

(P^P) ∨ (P^~Q) ^ ~Q = p ∨ p^(~Q^~Q) using idempotent law and associative law

p^(~Q^~Q) = P^~Q using idempotent law

(~Q ∨ (Q ^ ~P)) = (~Q ∨ Q) ^ (~Q ∨~P) using distributive law

(~Q ∨ Q) ^ (~Q ∨~P) = t ^ (~Q ∨ ~P) using negation property

t ^ (~Q ∨ ~P) = identity property

After this i have problem solving it. My equation stacks up like this:

(P ∨ p ∨ (P^~Q) ^ (~Q ∨ ~P)

Now i can combine P ∨ P tom make it P using idempotent law

So now it becomes like this:

P ∨ (P^~Q) ^ (~Q ∨ ~P) // i can still apply distributive law but it leads me to nowhere. I believe i have messed up something using the laws.

SE community please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The first conjunct of the LHS is :

> $P ∨ [(P ∧ ( P ∨ \sim Q)) ∧ \sim Q]$

i.e.

> $P ∨ [(P ∧ \sim Q) ∧ ( P ∨ \sim Q)]$.

By Distributivity:

> $$(P ∨ (P ∧ \sim Q)) ∧ (P ∨ ( P ∨ \sim Q)) \equiv (P \lor P) \land (P \lor \sim Q) \land (P \lor \sim Q) \equiv$$
>
> $$P \land (P \lor \sim Q).$$

Now, considering also the second conjunct of the LHS, that amounts to : $(\sim P ∨ \sim Q)$ we have :

> $$P \land (P \lor \sim Q) \land (\sim P ∨ \sim Q) \equiv P \land [(P \land \sim P) \lor \sim Q] \equiv$$
>
> $$ (P \land \sim Q).$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you got to `P∨[(P∧∼Q)∧(P∨∼Q)]`? Which property did you use to get to this?

Comment: @Saad - $[A \land (B \lor C) \land D] \equiv [(A \land D) \land (B \lor C)]$

Comment: Okay thanks. i see that you have got `(P∨(P∧∼Q))∧(P∨(P∨∼Q))`  you have distributed `P` before the conjunction but somehow didn't do it after the conjunction. It is as if you combined `P`s. Same goes after you get  `(P∨P)∧(P∨∼Q)∧(P∨∼Q)` and breaks it down to `P∧(P∨∼Q)`. Like you just combined `P V ~Q` into one. Can you please explain that part to me as well?